# Dot doesn't support any format in a newly installed Graphviz

Tags: fedora, graphviz, dot

I have installed Graphviz on Fedora using the recommended procedure [described](https://www.graphviz.org/download/) at GraphViz official site. However, I'm not able to convert a basic `hello.dot` file using `dot` command.

*My hello.dot file is:*

```
graph hello {
    Node1 [label="Hello, World!"]
}
```

*The error is:*

```
$ dot hello.dot -Tpng -o hello.png
Format: "png" not recognized. Use one of:
$
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like there is a bug in the official install. After running the command 'dot -c', the problem has been solved.

See [here](http://www.graphviz.org/mantisbt/view.php?id=2433) for more details.

Comment: Could you suggest how to do that if I do not have sudo command. (on server at Heroku)?

Comment: The problem is linked to a bug in the install process. Hence, in case `dot` has been installed in privileged mode, you need to have hand on the same privileged mode to fix the problem.

Comment: Surprisingly, even new releases (2.44) still as this issue...

Comment: The graphviz-gd package is also required. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35688320/graphviz-seems-doesnt-support-png-and-map