# Graphviz seems doesn't support png and map

Tags: graphviz

Hi I must convert a graph (a .dot)  to a map and to a png because I must generate dependencies graph with doxygen using graphviz.   But I have a error:

```
 error: problems opening map file
```

If I do dot -v I have

```
dot - graphviz version 2.38.0 (20140413.2041)
libdir = "/usr/local/lib/graphviz"
Activated plugin library: libgvplugin_dot_layout.so.6
Using layout: dot:dot_layout
Activated plugin library: libgvplugin_core.so.6
Using render: dot:core
Using device: dot:dot:core
The plugin configuration file:
/usr/local/lib/graphviz/config6
was successfully loaded.
render  :  dot fig map pic pov ps svg tk vml xdot
layout  :  circo dot fdp neato nop nop1 nop2 osage patchwork sfdp
twopi
textlayout  : 
device  :  canon cmap cmapx cmapx_np dot eps fig gv imap imap_np ismap                    
pic plain plain-ext pov ps ps2 svg svgz tk vml vmlz xdot xdot1.2 
loadimage   :  (lib) eps gif jpe jpeg jpg png ps svg
```

There isn't map and png for render

Moreover if I do   dot -Tpng

```
Format: "png" not recognized. Use one of: canon cmap cmapx cmapx_np   
dot eps fig gv imap imap_np ismap pic plain plain-ext pov ps ps2 svg 
tk vml vmlz xdot xdot1.2 xdot1.4
```

It seem that I have not the library for png and map.
How can I fix the problem?
(I do not remember how at the time I installed grapghviz)
(I'm working on Linux SO)

Answer (score 20):

Graphviz plugins need to be registered before they can be used. In **Windows**, open the command prompt as admin and type `dot -c` to register. You can verify it by typing `dot -v`

Comment: I work on Windows 10 and couldn't get Graphviz to work. His solution is simple and it works. Now if I can generate the graphics without errors! Thank you very much!

Comment: For Windows 10 and Symfony 5. * users. This solution works. Then to generate the graph from the CLI: php bin / console workflow: dump comment | dot -Tpng -o graph.png

Comment: For Windows 10 and Symfony 5. * users: First of all in your Symfony 5 project.  Install the library with composer req graphp / graphviz: ^ 0.2.2.

Comment: Why on earth can't the Windows installer do this? Or at the very least, tell us it needs to be done!

Comment: Chocolatey installer didn't do it either, which I agree is strange.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem on Centos 7 and I was able to solve it by
installing the `graphviz-gd` package with the command `yum install graphviz-gd`

After the installation I executed `dot -c` and now `dot -v` shows the following devices:

```
canon cmap cmapx cmapx_np dot eps fig gd gd2
gif gv imap imap_np ismap jpe jpeg jpg pic plain
plain-ext png pov ps ps2 svg svgz tk vml vmlz
vrml wbmp xdot xdot1.2 xdot1.4
```

Moreover I use the `cmapx` to create the map file.
Regards,
nemo

Comment: I had a similar issue when `graphviz` broke on Debian testing, and could not recognize the `jpeg` format. `apt-get install graphviz-dev` solved the problem.

Comment: I had a similar issue when installing `graphviz` using `homebrew` on Mac OS Sierra. Solved it by uninstalling and installing using `macports`

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue on macos 10.14. Solved the issue by reinstalling graphviz, and somehow it says 'not linked' as following

```
Warning: graphviz 2.47.3 is already installed, it's just not linked. To link this version, run: brew link graphviz
```

So end up with the following two commands:

```
brew install -f -s graphviz    
brew link --overwrite graphviz
```