# Doxygen fails to use Graphviz to generate dependency graph

Tags: doxygen, graphviz, dot

I am trying to use Doxygen to generate the documentation of my c++ program, and I wish to have the dependency graph as well. So I installed `graphviz-2.40.1`, the path to graphviz is shown below:

```
which dot
/usr/local/bin/dot
```

I turned on the `HAVE_DOT` to `YES`, and also set the `DOT_PATH` to be `/usr/local/bin/`.

However if I run `doxygen`, it fails to generate the dependency graph and throws me the error:

```
Format: "png" not recognized. Use one of: canon cmap cmapx cmapx_np dot dot_json eps fig gv imap imap_np ismap json json0 mp pic plain plain-ext pov ps ps2 svg svgz tk vml vmlz xdot xdot1.2 xdot1.4 xdot_json
error: Problems running dot: exit code=1, command='/usr/local/bin/dot', arguments='"/home/shiqihe/Documents/code/cpp/docs/doxygen/html/dg__main_8cpp__incl.dot" -Tpng -o "/home/shiqihe/Documents/code/cpp/docs/doxygen/html/dg__main_8cpp__incl.png"'
```

I have searched for the solution and find this: [soluiton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22427184/dot-doesnt-support-any-format-in-a-newly-installed-graphviz)

I tried `sudo dot -c` but it did not work. Still gave me the same error.

Any help? Thank you!

Comment: Which platform are you using? Which version of doxygen?

Comment: I am using doxygen-1.8.13, on ubuntu 18.04.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already mentioned the "solution" which says:

> It looks like there is a bug in the official install. After running the command 'dot -c', the problem has been solved.

The version you use does not support png, so:

- search for an executable that contains the png format
- create an executable yourself based on the graphviz dot code
- use another format in doxygen (when you use HTML as output you can use e,g. `svg` as `DOT_IMAGE_FORMAT`. (see documentation in e.g. http://doxygen.nl/manual/customize.html#minor_tweaks_dynsection)

Comment: Thank you, problem solved! I changed `DOT_IMAGE_FORMAT = ` form `png` to `svg`, then everything works just fine. And for HTML if the browser is IE +9, you need to set `HTML_FILE_EXTENSION` to `xhtml`.